# Github API - trying to access multiple pages of /users

Tags: api, github

I am playing around with Github's API and I noticed that they allow anyone to request all users that have signed up in chronological order.

```
https://api.github.com/users
```

http://developer.github.com/v3/users/

I was trying to get the second page but for some reason their pagination isn't working for me. I wasn't sure what I was doing wrong.

```
https://api.github.com/users?page=2
https://api.github.com/users?start_page=2
```

http://developer.github.com/v3/ Under "Pagination".

Anyone know the right way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out the returned HTTP headers for the `https://api.github.com/users` resource. Specifically, look for the `Link` header, which will look like this:

```
Link:<https://api.github.com/users?since=135>; rel="next", <https://api.github.com/users{?since}>; rel="first"
```

So, what you need to do is do an HTTP GET on `https://api.github.com/users?since=135` to get the next page. After that, check the `Link` header again and you will get to the next page, etc. Also notice the provided URI template `https://api.github.com/users{?since}` which enables you to start at any `id`.